# Integrating AWeber Issue

Tags: php, aweber

I am integrating **AWeber** on my site but i found problem and must say the documentation is not too clear .

```
<?php
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');

$consumerKey    = '***'; # put your credentials here
$consumerSecret = '***'; # put your credentials here
$accessKey      = '***'; # put your credentials here
$accessSecret   = '***'; # put your credentials here
$account_id     = '***'; # put the Account ID here
$list_id        = '***'; # put the List ID here

$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

But I don't know, from where I get `aweber_api/aweber_api.php` and `$consumerKey` , `$consumerSecret` , `$accessKey` , `$list_id`,`$account_id` and `$accessSecret` . And I made account on [AWeber.com](http://www.aweber.com/) and there I don't find these credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer key and secret are issued by the https://labs.aweber.com web site when you sign up for a developer account and "create and app".  You then use the API library with those two values to kick off an authorization process (following the OAuth 1.0a standard).  That process will give you the access key and secret.

Finally, you use those two pairs of keys to have your app authenticate to the API each time it requests data:

- The Consumer Key and Consumer Secret identify your app
- The Access Key and Access Secret say to the API, "I am logging in to this specific AWeber account"

Once your application has authenticated itself, you can use the library to fetch the account ID and the appropriate List ID for whichever list you want to access.

AWeber has a good tutorial, including sample code, that walks you through their OAuth process here:

https://labs.aweber.com/getting_started/private#private_connect_oauth

Comment: What are the accessKey and SecretKey? Where to find it?

Comment: Did you try to by your tutorial? I cannot receive any accessKey nor accessSecret. And absolutely unclear how to do it for a developer account.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a developer account on Aweber to get these.

Go to: https://labs.aweber.com/

Then create an app to get these values.